# Sitemap for dynamic website - codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have a dynamic website designed with Codeigniter 3 and I am working on the sitemap part as a newbie.

I found the `library sitemap-php` from  [evert/sitemap-php](https://github.com/evert/sitemap-php)  but I can't make it run.

From now this is what I did, I put the **Sitemap.php** file into my library folder

**Controller:**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Deals extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url', 'form', 'security');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('email'); 
    $this->load->model('deal_model');
    $this->load->helper(array('cookie','custom','text'));
}

    public function Sitemap(){ 

      $this->load->library('Sitemap'); 
      $sitemap = new Sitemap('https://www.mywebsite.com');
      $sitemap->setPath('/public_html/Sitemap/'); // I created a folder Sitemap into my public folder
      $sitemap->setFilename('sitemap');
      $sitemap->addItem('/', '1.0', 'daily', 'Today');
      $sitemap->createSitemapIndex('https://www.mywebsite.com/sitemap/', 'Today');
}
```

Then when I go to https://www.mywebsite.com/sitemap/, I have an **Error 404.**

Could you guide me to solve my issue.

Thanks

Comment: Did you add this at the beginning of the **Sitemap.php** , as stated in the [Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html?highlight=custom%20library): `defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');`

Comment: Try to **bypass the constructor** as it is already constructed by CodeIgniter.  Remove: 

`$sitemap = new Sitemap('https://www.mywebsite.com');`

and replace it with

`$sitemap->setDomain('https://www.mywebsite.com');`

Comment: @jonathan Yes, I checked I have the defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); at the beginning of the file .
Also I changed the $sitemap = new Sitemap('https://www.mywebsite.com'); with $sitemap->setDomain('https://www.mywebsite.com');
But still the error 404, in the sitemap folder, I don't have any xml files.

Comment: Do you see any more Info about the 404 in the Webserver logs?

Comment: the server log is giving me nothing. I have my own 404 page, and when I try to access the mywebsite.com/sitemap, I am landing on that page. I tried to play with the controller, Htaccess, route but nothing. Looks like the library is not executed.

Comment: I am not familiar with that lib but reading the docs it sounds like you need to *run* that code to generate a static XML file.  The code above looks like the code to generate an XML file in `/public_html/Sitemap/`, and you are visiting that URL looking for the XML.  But did you run the code to generate it?

Comment: Thats right you never call `startSitemap()` for example

Comment: @dont-panic & jonathan, yes this is what I understood the library is creating a xml file into the Sitemap folder that you access through URL. I don't think I am running the script, it might be why nothing is happening. I need to read more on how to do that, because I am not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for that library describe that it generates a static XML file.  The code you've shown will do that - but your code is in a Library, and you have not *run* it yet.  You need to run it, then it will generate an XML file as you've specified, in `/public_html/Sitemap/`.  From your description you are looking for the XML before doing anything to generate it, and it does not (yet) exist.

From your updated code, you now have the code to *generate* the static XML available as a Controller method.  According to [the standard Codeigniter routing conventions](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html), the method you have created is accessible at:

```
http://your-site/deals/Sitemap
```

(Maybe you've also [set up some routes](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) so it is accessible at other URIs also.)

Visit that URL, once, to generate the static XML file at `/public_html/Sitemap/sitemap.xml`.  Assuming your code works, you should then be able to browse the XML at

```
http://your-site/Sitemap/sitemap.xml
```

Side note: AFAIK Codeigniter convention is for capitalised Controller file and class names (`Deal.php` and `Deal`), but all lower-case method names (`sitemap()` instead of `Sitemap()`).  You can see examples of this [in the Controller docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#methods) I linked above.  I am not sure if it matters, just pointing it out.

Comment: Yet it makes a lot of sense for me now. I visited the url  http://your-site/deals/Sitemap to run the code, and I got an error  "Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script", I am moving which is good, I will try to solve this issue by reading online. But at least something is happening.

Comment: OK - it sounds like you have a `Namespace` but it is not the first line in your code.  Up to you but if you are just learning I'd suggest starting out with [the simple templates like they have in the docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world), or eg [the `Welcome.php` controller](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/controllers/Welcome.php) that comes pre-bundled.  You can always change them once things are running.

Comment: Yes I think, I will start from here, check everything and educate myself more on how CI works.